Get all CELLS from a specific Datatable ROW
So I'm adding a row to my datatable using
var newRow = myTable.row.add([
    questionText,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
  ]).draw(false);

And I then want to get all the cells from that row and assign ids and onclick elements and classes and whatnot.
I tried
newRow.cells().every( function () {
    var cell = $(this.node());
});

but this iterates over all the cells in the entire table, for some reason. I've been looking online and through the documentation, but nothing I find seems to work. I found a plethora of example using data to change the cells values, but I don't want to change their values I want to edit the elements themselves...
any help?

Does it work when you use newRow.cells() alone? Or is it specifically for getting them one by one.

your newRow variable isn't the new row...it's myTable.  You can confirm by console logging newRow and inspect the result in the console tab of your browser's developer tools.

Check out the second example here, where it shows how to use node().

PS, that will give you the new row, and from there, you should be able to iterate over that row's cells.

Just to add to what devlincarnate wrote... "this iterates over all the cells in the entire table, for some reason" - as explained in the official documentation: "Returns: DataTables API instance with the newly added row in its result set.". And using the example from the documentation, you can get each <td> for your <tr> node: $(rowNode).find('td').each (function() { console.log( this ); });

Oh of course....I was so focused on trying to get them through the plugin I forgot getting the row itself and iterating over its cells would be infinitely easier -_-
Thanks
